# Is there any way to set order in type library?

Tags: delphi, delphi-6, typelib

In my project I have many methods and properties described in type library .
And when I want to edit some method or a property ,it's a bit difficult to find the
needed item from list in Type Library wizard tool. Is there any way to rearrange them ?
I'm using Delphi v.6

Comment: When you re-order them, you will be breaking compatibility. The order in which items appear in an interface is significant.

Comment: @David But as long as his code compiles he won't have a problem, though? Only when he regenerates the type library, all his ordering will be undone.

Comment: @Jan Problem is for existing code that uses the interface

Comment: @JanDoggan: once an interface has been defined and code is using it, it CANNOT be changed without breaking that code. That includes order of methods, especially when vtables are used. That is a fundamental rule of COM.  There is no option to sort a TypeLibrary's contents.